# Storing events in a dictionary, and then raising them

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, dictionary

I managed to get a dictionary that can store events:

```
'Terrible .NET events... where's sender and e?!
Public Event ItHappened()
Public Event ItAlmostHappened()

Private mapping As New Dictionary(Of String, System.Delegate) From _
    {{"happened", ItHappenedEvent},
     {"almostHappened", ItAlmostHappenedEvent}}
```

Great! Now that I have this dictionary, I can convert a stringly-typed event stream into *I'm-a-real-boy* events! I even figured out how to call them:

```
 mapping(key).DynamicInvoke()
```

But alas `mapping(key)` is null... even after adding a handler for the event. If I update the value in the dictionary to `mapping("happened") = ItHappenedEvent` after adding an handler, then all is well. Is there a way I accomplish something similar programmatically? Or otherwise store off a string -> event map to translate string input into events at runtime?

**Edit:**

Real code as requested. This is part of a mechanism to allow us to pass commands to a WinService running on the server. The "do the simplest thing you can possibly do" approach lead us to using files placed on the server as a signaling mechanism.

```
Public Class CommandChecker
  Implements IDisposable

  Public Event RefreshPlannableStations()

  Private _knownCommmands As New Dictionary(Of String, System.Delegate) From _
    {{"refreshStations", RefreshPlannableStationsEvent}}

  Private WithEvents _fsw As FileSystemWatcher

  Public Sub New(ByVal path As String)
    Me._fsw = New FileSystemWatcher(path, "*.command")
  End Sub

  Private Sub fsw_Created(ByVal sender As Object,
                          ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles _fsw.Created
    If Me._knownCommmands.ContainsKey(key) Then
      Me._knownCommmands(key).DynamicInvoke()
      'Delete file to acknowledge command
    EndIf
  End Sub

  'Snipped IDisposable stuff
End Class
```

Elsewhere, we create this class, and then subscribe to its event.

```
Me._checker = New CommandChecker()
AddHandler Me._checker.RefreshPlannableStations, AddressOf OnRefreshStations
```

Comment: Is this an exercise in curiosity, or is there a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Please provide real code that we can reproduce.

Comment: Use the [Custom keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf33s4w7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to define a custom event.  Use the accessors to update the directory.

Comment: @HansPassant, do I really need all that code every time I want to create my own custom event? That make me want to change this class to be able to `RegisterCommand(commandName As String, handler As Action)` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a layer of indirection will help you here. Instead of mapping the string to the event directly, map the string to an action that will raise the event, like so:

```
Private mapping As New Dictionary(Of String, Action) From _
    {{"happened", Sub() RaiseEvent ItHappened()},
     {"almostHappened", Sub() RaiseEvent ItAlmostHappened()}}
```

Comment: Ah, much better! Amazing what an extra layer can do at times :)